# jQuery datepicker maxDate is not working correctly for me

Tags: jquery

So this is my code and from what I can tell it should work fine but it in fact is not working as expected. I think it's quite obvious as to what I want to happen which is only allow for 2 days in advance of the set date. In this case its 2-20-13 to 2-22-13 but this is giving me 2-20-13 to 2-24-13

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    minDate: new Date(2013, 2 -1, 20), 
    maxDate: '+2D'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxDate: '+2D'` gives you 2 days from today, not 2 days from your start date.

[jQuery UI Referece](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes, the answer was RTFM like always.